# HTML jQuery Survey Form ends abruptly

Tags: html, jquery, css, forms, jsfiddle

I have written a html with jquery to create a survey form but everytime I come to the textarea it gives out a 404 Error. When I play around it seems something might be wrong with my ifs? Sorry for bad coding I am new.

What I've done so far. I have created the divs that contain the 6 questions. 3 of those questions are radio buttons and 2 are textareas and 1 are contact information. Everytime a question has been answered I created with jquery an animate that fades one div out and fades one div in. I had to write ifs to block the next button and thats all It worked very smoothly but as soon as I added some ifs all got kinda destroyed and deleting back the ifs keeps the error for some reason

the jsfiddle:

```
 [JSFiddle][1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahkvcmsy/2/)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Given that you have a link to JS Fiddle marked as code, it looks like Stackoverflow automatically warned you about that and, instead of doing what you were hacked, you hacked your way around that check. That isn't going to win you any friends.

Comment: Your question as it is, without code, is too broad for any real troubleshooting or helpful guesswork.